# Twit to twitter using MGTwitterEngine not Working

Tags: iphone, twitter, mgtwitterengine

I have to integrate Twitter API in iPhone(4.2 and above).For this I am using SA_OAuthTwitterEngine + MGTwitterEngine classes.

I register applicaiton to www.twitter.com/apps and pass Consumer key and Consumer secret to controller my code is this.

```
if(!_engine){
    _engine = [[SA_OAuthTwitterEngine alloc] initOAuthWithDelegate:self];
    _engine.consumerKey    = KCONSKEY;
    _engine.consumerSecret = KCONSECKEY;  
}

UIViewController *controller = [SA_OAuthTwitterController controllerToEnterCredentialsWithTwitterEngine:_engine delegate:self];

if (controller){
    [self presentModalViewController: controller animated: YES];
}
```

I have seen [this](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/twitter-api-iphone/) and [this](http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/09/16/dealing-with-the-twitter-oauth-apocalypse/) example also. In both example we can’t able to twit.. Also, in both example, I ‘m getting error:
 `failed with error: Error Domain=HTTP Code=401 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (HTTP error 401.)”` 
Can Please, any one give me suggestion how to overcome this problem?

Comment: Did you find any solution? Because i have same problem. If you find than please tell me.I am using same link as you used.

Comment: No. till now  didn't solved my problem

Comment: I got the solution.App must need permission of read-write. So giving permission error will not come.

Comment: Ok..But I have tried with permission.Anyways, I will try again

Answer (score 1):

There are changes for API, I guess the MGTwitterEngine is not updated and please do refer the developer site for more information.

http://www.readwriteweb.com/archives/twitter_changes_api_fails_to_notify_developers.php

https://dev.twitter.com/docs

Comment: if you find this answer appropriate can you accept it as an answer ??

Answer (score 0):

```
[_engine sendUpdate: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Already Updated. \n%@", [NSDate date]]];
```