# Twitter MGTwitterEngine not redirect to iphone application

Tags: iphone, ios, twitter, callback, mgtwitterengine

I have integrated MGTwitterEngine in my iOS application to tweet. Twitter was working fine till last week. I have not made any change in iOS code. But today after login, Twitter does not redirect me to my iOS application. Instead it is showing the message "Please Wait..."

How can I fix this?

Comment: some says there are change in twitter API. refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11933666/twit-to-twitter-using-mgtwitterengine-not-working

Comment: Any update? is any one find solution for this?